# Python: Transparently dealing with zipped and normal files

Tags: python, zip

I'd like to write a python script to process some log files. The application produces about a gigabyte of logs a week, and at the end of the week it zips these logs down to about 50 megs a each.

I don't want to have to separate code for processing zip files and non-zipped log files, i.e. I don't want `if (zip) then (blah1) else (blah2)` all throughout the code, ideally such a check should only occur once, and the rest of the code should be the same. Is there any way/library that unifies zip/normal files so the same code can be used to read them.

I do not need to do writes. Note, I'm dealing with directories (and zipped directories) here, not just individual files, so I need to be able to move around both the same.

Answer (score 4):

My basic approach would be to abstract a zip file and a directory so they have similar interfaces. Here I've chosen to consider the zip file "canonical" and simply implemented the `zipfile`'s `namelist()` and `open()` methods for directories. (this is similar to Mark Hildreth's answer only I'm not designing a whole new API.) You could implement more if you need to, of course.

A factory function `opencontainer()` returns either a `ZipFile` instance or a `Directory` instance depending on what you give it. (You could also just use a `__new__()` method on `Directory` to do this.)

You can then iterate over `namelist()` and open files inside the container using the container's `open()` method. At that point you have either a `file` object or a file-like object from a zip file, and the APIs for these are already similar by design.

```
import zipfile, os

class Directory(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
    def namelist(self):
        return os.listdir(self.path)
    def open(self, name):
        return open(os.path.join(self.path, name))

def opencontainer(path):
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(path):
        return zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    return Directory(path)

container = opencontainer(path)
for logname in container.namelist():
    logtext = container.open(logname).read()
```

This is a very rough sketch of a solution, and probably needs some beefed-up error handling and resource management (a context manager might make sense to make sure that files get closed).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of any library that does this, but it doesn't sound too hard to write. Basically, you do as you say: check once at the start, then react based on the type of file you've found. The "[strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)" is a common pattern in programming that could look something like this...

```
class ZipFileAccessStrategy(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
         ...open the zipfile...

    def get_file(self, filename):
         ...get a file from the archive....

    def get_files(self, directory):
         ...get a list of all files in a directory in the zip file...

class DirectoryAccessStrategy(object):
    def __init__(self, directory):
         ...store the name of the directory...

    def get_file(self, filename):
         ...get a file relative to this directory....

    def get_files(self, directory):
         ...get a list of all files in a specific path relative to the directory...

filename = '...'
if is_zipfile(filename):
    strategy = ZipFileAccessStrategy(filename)
else:
    strategy = DirectoryAccessStrategy(filename)

# Now we can access whether Zip File or Directory using a common interface
file_list = strategy.get_files('/')
f = strategy.get_file(file_list[0])
```

I've ignored some implementation details, and there's proper opening/closing of files to worry about as well. However, hopefully this gives you a general idea.